# PHP Filtering Function

Tags: php

I've built a blog similar to wordpress. On my home page, I take the entire blog post, throw it  through a function, and only display an excerpt of it. I want to go through and shrink my videos to a specific width/height. The code in the post could look like:

```
[vimeo width="700" height="400"] // (the 700 & 400 could be any values).
```

I basically want to find that, then change it to:

```
[vimeo width="300" height="200"] // this will be preset/hard coded.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regular expressions through `preg_replace()` to do the filtering.  Just load your whole blog post into `$BlogPost`.  The RegEx pattern may need to be altered to allow for variations in syntax and spacing (i.e. `width = '700'`, etc.)

```
<?php
$FilteredBlogPost = preg_replace('/(.*vimeo width=")\d+(" height=")\d+(".*)/im', '${1}300${2}200${3}', $BlogPost);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

unless you want to scrape the video, put it on your server, resize it with some video dedicated libraries and then stream it from your server, the solution is client related (ie: HTML. not PHP)

[Here is a nice tutorial](http://www.freewebs.com/balmyjanuary/Tutorials/YouTubeVideoResizing.htm) on how to achieve that with youtube videos - i think exactly the same applies in your case too

Comment: Hello. Actually, all I want to do is just have my code replace the width and the height. I'm not concerned about resizing the video, I just want it displayed with a different width/height. The code in my previous post ([vimeo width="<i want to change>" height="<i want to change>")